# gevent socket with UDP connection

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, gevent

I have spent many hours on this problem but I could not figure out what is going wrong.

I have two programs in python. P1 program uses gevent socket modeul to create two types of connection i.e., TCP and UDP. Each connection is created in a separate greenlet. Program1 runs okay.

Then I have another program P2 that uses Popen from gevent subprocess to invoke P1 as an external program like this:

```
sub = Popen("python p1.py 1", stdout = PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

As the P1 starts, a greenlet with UDP connection crashes with following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
result = self.run(self.args, *self.kwargs)
File "gtest_runner.py", line 883, in run
self.sock.sendto(data, master_addr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 475, in sendto
ret_val = sock.sendto(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
<Greenlet at 0x7f86a0140730: <bound method Beacon.run of <__main_.Beacon instance at 0x7f86a2c4aa28>>> failed with TypeError
```

I am using Python 2.7 on ubuntu 14.

Anticipated thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you run it using regular `subprocess` module?

Comment: No, first I was using regular subprocess module and then I changed to gevent subprocess to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: where does the traceback comesfrom? Is it an exception inside P1? If it is then P1 does not run ok. Try to [create the shortest program that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I found out my mistake. When P1 is invoked by the P2, it changes the port number in `master_addr` to a string type. That's why, `sendto` function crashes. But the strange thing is that it does not affect the TCP socket when you provide the port number in string format.